# Obtaining wifi name in iOS

Tags: objective-c, cydia

I'm developing an app for Cydia. Is there a way to get the name of actual connected wifi network?

There seems to be a way with the Apple SDK, any ideas?

This is my action:

```
-(IBAction)addCurrent:(id)sender {
if ([[objc_getClass("SBWiFiManager") sharedInstance] currentNetworkName] != @"") {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathFile];
        NSMutableArray *networks = [dict objectForKey:@"Networks"];
        [networks addObject:[[objc_getClass("SBWiFiManager") sharedInstance] currentNetworkName]];
        [dict setObject:networks forKey:@"Networks"];
        [dict writeToFile:pathFile atomically: YES];
        [dict release];
}
```

When I click the button connected to the action, does not add anything to the plist file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will require a jailbroken device:

```
[[objc_getClass("SBWiFiManager") sharedInstance] currentNetworkName]
```

Comment: Does anyone know what SB stands for?

Comment: Writing "NSString * networkName = [[objc_getClass (" SBWiFiManager ") sharedInstance] currentNetworkName]," it seems that the string is null.

Comment: SpringBoard is NOT a Cydia app. SpringBoard is basically "Finder" in iOS, where your icons / dock sit, etc.

Comment: I know, I will say it to JustSid. Like this:
JustSid SB stands for Springboard
WrightsCS yes, it's for a cydia app (Jailbroken devices). 
Got it now?

Comment: ah, okay. So if you know how to hook into SpringBoard this will get you want you need. You will need the `SBWifiManager` classes imported. You should also look into Theos and how to make dylibs.

Comment: CHDeclareClass(SBWiFiManager);? Still return a null string

Comment: are you importing the headers? or making dummy classes for `SBWifiManager`?

Comment: I'm importing SpringBoard/SBWifiManager.h

Comment: where are you using the code, and maybe you can edit your question with the entire code you are using and a little more detail on how you are implementing it.

Comment: you will no be able to call this from an App. You would need to send an `NSNotification` to a dylib. The dylib is what works inside SpringBoard, not apps. You can then have your dylib send back a notification with the network name, or write it to a file that your app can read.

Comment: Can you write a little example?

Comment: There are quite a few examples on the internet. If you want to contact me outside of S.O. see my profile for contact information and maybe we can work something out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my 3rd party library for this, it uses only Public API:
https://github.com/Krivoblotsky/SSIDObserver